# Javascript substring character from string with special character '/'

Tags: javascript, substring

I am trying extract some characters from string. I tried the [example at here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_substr) by using these code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract parts of the string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "2017/01/23";
    var res = str.substr(5, 6);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My date format as `yyyy/mm/dd` and I wanted to extract the month out. However, with the code above, when I tried `substr(5,6)`, it returns me `'01/23'` rather than `'01`' itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `substr` is [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), so you need 2 instead of 6 here:

```js
var str = "2017/01/23";

console.log(
  str.substr(5, 2)
)
```

Comment: Oh shit that was a silly mistake. Thanks so much for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you want str.substring(5, 7)!

Comment: I think it's 5,2

Comment: Different method, substring vs. substr :]